# Remove a word from a string and maintain comma within them

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a string s3 which let us suppose contain "Alabama, Alaska, Arizona" and
let us suppose that txtResidentState.Text contains "Alaska". Now I want to remove "Alaska" from s3 string and the final string should be "Alabama, Alaska". The final string should be added to txtJurisdiction. Also I want to maintain "," within words.
I have written following lines of code

```
string CommonJurisdiction = s3;
string Result;
int index= CommonJurisdiction.IndexOf(txtResidentState.Text.ToString());

if(index != -1)
{
   Result = CommonJurisdiction.Remove(index);
   txtJurisdiction.Text = Result;
}
```

The above code does not work.

Comment: You want to remove "Alaska" but in the resulting string the "Alaska" word is still there? Please be more clear on this

Answer (score 0):

You should split the array and then check if the item exists. Then remove it and reconstruct the string.

```
string[] commonJurisdiction = s3.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
// make sure the spaces are filtered out by trimming

string result;
int index = commonJurisdiction.IndexOf(txtResidentState.Text);

if(index >= 0)
{
    commonJurisdiction.Remove(index);
    result = string.Join(", ", commonJurisdiction);
    txtJurisdiction.Text = Result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Split`, `Except` and `String.Join`:

```
string wordsToRemove =  txtResidentState.Text.Trim().Split(',');
string[] words = s3.Split(',');
txtJurisdiction.Text = String.Join(",", words.Except(wordsToRemove));
```

This works with a single word `Alaska` but also if the TextBox contains `Alaska,Alabama`.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to check that the words to remove actually exist in 's3' before splitting and joining again? Otherwise you'll be splitting and rejoining for nothing.

Comment: @sr28: depends. Makes the code more complex, maybe for nothing. Because you need to split anyway and then you have to use `Intersect...Any()` to check if a word is contained. So you're doing most of the work only to check if you have to do some work. Then i'd prefer to do full work always and have simple code. Optimize if i have a performance issue which is unlikely here.